# UTC to local time in millis using JodaTime

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, datetime-conversion

I am attempting to show transactions over a certain time period using Jodatime.

Our server requires a start date and end date to be in UTC (which is probably obvious). Therefore any business logic around these is using DateTime object with the timezone set to `DateTimeZone.UTC`, e.g.

```
mStartDate = DateTime.now(UTC).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

That works well except when it comes to **display** the time I don't know how to augment it for the local (system default) timezone. Ideally I would like to use the `DateUtils` [formatDateRange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateRange(android.content.Context,%20java.util.Formatter,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) function passing in two local timestamps. But the `getMillis()` function doesn't seem to account for local offsets:

[image: Timestamps returning same milisecond times]

I have also tried this:

```
mTimePeriodTitle.setText(DateUtils.formatDateRange(mContext, f, mStartDate.getMillis(),
    mEndDate.getMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME,
    TimeZone.getDefault().getID()).toString());
```

But it hasn't made any difference. So my question is how can I get a nicely formatted local date range with 2 UTC timestamps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `DateTime` is in UTC and you want to convert it to another timezone, you can use the `withZone` method to do the conversion.

For the examples below, my default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo` (you can check yours using `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`):

```
// create today's date in UTC
DateTime mStartDate = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
// date/time in UTC
System.out.println(mStartDate); // 2017-06-13T00:00:00.000Z
// date/time in my default timezone (America/Sao_Paulo)
System.out.println(mStartDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())); // 2017-06-12T21:00:00.000-03:00
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-13T00:00:00.000Z
> 2017-06-12T21:00:00.000-03:00

Note that the `withZone` method correctly converts the date and time to my timezone (in `America/Sao_Paulo` the current offset is `UTC-03:00`), so it was adjusted accordingly.

If you want to get just the time (hour/minute/second), you can use `toLocalTime()` method:

```
System.out.println(mStartDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalTime()); // 21:00:00.000
```

The output is:

> 21:00:00.000

If you want another format (for example, don't print the 3 digits of fraction-of-second), you can use a `DateTimeFormatter`. The good thing is that you can set a timezone in the formatter, so you don't need to convert the `DateTime`:

```
// create formatter for hour/minute/second, set it with my default timezone
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(fmt.print(mStartDate)); // 21:00:00
```

The output is:

> 21:00:00

To get your range, you can use one of the methods above with your `DateTime`'s (`mStartDate` and `mEndDate`), and use the `DateTimeFormatter` to change to whatever format you need.

---

**PS:** what I think you're missing when using `getMillis()` is that both datetimes (in UTC and in default timezone) represents **the same instant**. You are just converting this instant to a local time, but the millis is the same (think that, right now, at this moment, everybody in the world are in the same instant (the same millis), but their local times might be different depending on where they are). So, when converting a UTC `DateTime` to another timezone, we're just finding what is the local time in that zone, that corresponds to the same millis.

You can check this using the `getMillis()` method on both objects:

```
System.out.println(mStartDate.getMillis()); // 1497312000000
System.out.println(mStartDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).getMillis()); // 1497312000000
```

Note that, even if I convert the object to another timezone, the millis remains the same (`1497312000000`). That's because both represent the same instant, I'm just moving them to another timezone where the respective local time is different.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time it's being discontinued and replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. If that's your case, you can consider using the new Date/Time API, but if you have a big codebase using Joda or don't want to migrate it now, you can desconsider the rest of the answer.

Anyway, even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). I'm not sure if it's already available to all Android versions (but see the alternative below).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's a way to use it, with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To get the current date at start of the day in UTC, you can do:

```
// UTC's today at start of the day
ZonedDateTime utc = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(utc); // 2017-06-13T00:00Z
```

First I did `LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to find the current local date in UTC. If I use just `LocalDate.now()`, it'll get the current date in my default timezone, which is not what we want (it might be different from UTC, depending on where - and when - you are and what the default timezone is).

Then I used `atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to get the start of the day at UTC. I know it sounds redundant to use UTC twice, but the API allows us to use any timezone in this method, and IMO it makes explicit what timezone we want (if the date is in a timezone with Daylight Saving changes, the start of day might not be midnight - the timezone parameter is to guarantee that the correct value is set).

The output is:

> 2017-06-13T00:00Z

To convert to my default timezone, I can use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, which in my case returns `America/Sao_Paulo`. To convert it and get only the local time part, just do:

```
System.out.println(utc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()); // 21:00
```

The output is:

> 21:00

If you want to change it, you can also use a formatter:

```
// formatter for localtime (hour/minute/second)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(fmt.format(utc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()))); // 21:00:00
```

The output is:

> 21:00:00

Comment: The PS is very important! Milliseconds since the epoch are the same across all time zones because the epoch is January 1 1970 **UTC** and doesn’t change with time zone.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the project advising migration to the *java.time* classes.

### Zones

> Our server requires a start date and end date to be in UTC (which is probably obvious).

Yes, use UTC for much of your business logic, as well as for logging, storing, and exchanging date-time values. Think of UTC as the One True Time, with other zones being mere variations. Apply a time zone only when required for specific rules in your business logic or for presentation to the user.

For a value in UTC, use `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

To see the same moment in a particular time zone, assign a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId zTunis = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTunis = instant.atZone( zTunis ) ;
```

See the same moment in yet another zone.

```
ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = instant.atZone( zAuckland );
```

### Strings

> So my question is how can I get a nicely formatted local date range with 2 UTC timestamps?

After making the adjustments from UTC to a time zone as shown above, generate strings to represent their value.

To generate a String representing any of those objects in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z

```
String output = zdtAuckland.toString() :
```

> 2018-01-23T14:23:45.123456+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

To generate a String in other formats, define a formatting pattern. Or let *java.time* automatically localize.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> mardi 23 janvier 2018 à 14:23:45 heure avancée de la Nouvelle-Zélande

Note that time zone has *nothing* to do with `Locale`. One is for content, the other is for presentation.

## Interval

When representing a pair of moments, a couple of start-stop moments, use the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library (linked below). This class represents a pair of `Instant` objects.

Its `toString` method generates a string is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For other formats, and for adjustments into other zones, use the code seen above to apply to each `Instant` a `ZoneId` to generate a `ZonedDateTime`. Access each `Instant` via `getStart` & `getEnd`.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( start , stop ) ;
```

> interval.toString(): 2007-12-03T10:15:30/2007-12-04T10:15:30

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).